Upgrade ubuntu from 22.04 to 24
The upgrade doesnt work from 22 to 24.
After some research and test i found  this error :
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up evdi (1.14.8-133) ...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: evdi-1.14.8
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
dpkg: error processing package evdi (--configure):
 installed evdi package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 3
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of displaylink-driver:
 displaylink-driver depends on evdi (>= 1.14.7); however:
  Package evdi is not configured yet.
 displaylink-driver depends on evdi (<< 1.15.0); however:
  Package evdi is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package displaylink-driver (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 evdi
 displaylink-driver

Here the result of dkms status
sudo dkms status
evdi/1.14.8: added
evdi/5.2.14: added

Not sure what is going on.
Anyone knows how to remove one .
Thanks

try sudo apt purge evdi and reinstall it again

It looks like you have added the driver to the DKMS but not installed it. You need to install so it is built and installed for the current kernel. (When the kernel is upgraded it will automatically then build and install for that one too.)
To make a module package installable from the DKMS see the following link.
https://schneide.blog/2015/08/10/packaging-kernel-modulesdrivers-using-dkms/
DKMS (with example driver)
Use dkms status to identify the device driver (RTL8812BU) for each succesfully built kernel. Your original driver source could/will have an uninstall to uninstall it. If not then you could uninstall it as follows: -
Typical output of dkms status
rtl8812bu/X.XX.X.X, 6.8.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812bu/X.XX.X.X, 6.8.0-44-generic, x86_64: installed

Typical removal from the dkms. If it is removed it should also stop the driver installing but you might have to reboot to achieve this. You need to use your details of the driver you have installed but here are are some examples. (Note: Only uninstall from non-active or broken driver kernels.)
dkms remove rtl8812bu/x.x.x.x --all
dkms remove rtl8812bu/x.x.x.x -k  6.8.0-45-generic -a x86_64


sudo dkms remove -m evdi/1.14.8 -k --all

and
sudo dkms remove -m evdi/5.2.14  -k --all

This will remove both evdi version from dkms tree.
sudo apt purge evdi

I think this is from a ppa.
Make sure you have pocket universe enabled.
sudo apt install  evdi-dkms


For those who don't know how to enable universe, type sudo add-apt-repository universe
